# How do I view the DeletionPolicy on a given CloudFormation resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I created a CloudFormation stack and then updated it using a changeset to change DeletionPolicy to Retain.

Is there any way to view the DeletionPolicy on a resource in a live stack to tell whether it was set correctly?

Comment: Are you looking for something other than going to the console and checking the stack's deletion policy?

Comment: @404 I want to see the deletion policy on each individual resource, and thereby predict what cloudformation will attempt to do with it when the stack is deleted.

Comment: As an anecdote, for any who hit this question in the future. I had a LogGroup I wanted to retain.  Added DeletionPolicy: "Retain" to my CF template (along with one other minor change), updated the stack.  Then deleted the stack. and my LogGroups were retained.  YMMV

Answer (score 3):

[describe-stack-resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stack-resource.html) does not currently return `DeletionPolicy`

Read the [`DeletionPolicy` documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html) for default `DeletionPolicy` values, search the template itself for `DeletionPolicy` overrides, and ensure your CloudFormation [stack status](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-describing-stacks.html#w2ab1c15c15c17c11) reached the status you were expecting (probably `CREATE_COMPLETE` / `UPDATE_COMPLETE`)