# AWS S3 DeletionPolicy - Add after creation and verify setting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I've created a bucket without a DeletionPolicy and want to add it.  Updated our configuration (in our serverless.yml), and we now see the `DeletionPolicy: retain` in the cloud-formation template.

However, based on [this blurb](https://www.kevinslin.com/notes/057b1ab7-8c72-4117-aee4-fb8234d960e3.html):

> One quirk in the update template workflow is that DeletionPolicy
> cannot be updated by itself but must accompany some other change that
> "add, modify or delete properties" of an existing resource. A fun fact
> about the AWS::S3::Bucket resource: it cannot be updated after
> creation. Good news: this does not apply to the DeletionPolicy
> attribute. Bad news: CFN won't pick up the changes unless another
> property of the "immutable" S3 bucket is updated.

I've searched for quite a while, and I cannot determine how to query the S3 bucket and determine *if* the `DeletionPolicy` is actually set or not.  I don't see where this is exposed in the AWS console, nor do I see in the AWS cli where this can be queried.  It doesn't appear to be in the Bucket Policy as far as I can tell.

How do I validate the `DeletionPolicy` is actually set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [linked article](https://www.kevinslin.com/notes/057b1ab7-8c72-4117-aee4-fb8234d960e3.html) (from 1/12/2014) is outdated. I just did the following:

Deployed a stack containing

```
MyBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    .
    .
    .
```

Verified it deployed successfully, then deployed

```
MyBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    .
    .
    .
```

Verified it deployed successfully, then deleted my stack, and verified `MyBucket` is still present in S3.

Comment: Yes, but how do I verify that w/o attempting to delete it?  As far as I can tell, that flag is totally hidden from the web console and API.  I simply want to validate that it is set on my bucket w/o attempting to delete the bucket

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58316530/how-do-i-view-the-deletionpolicy-on-a-given-cloudformation-resource) is almost a duplicate of yours, and the docs say its answer is still correct: you can't. You need to trust that the `DeletionPolicy` update in the cfn template means the bucket config really has changed, which, coupled with the proof of concept above, I hope is enough to put you at ease. If you need further reassurance [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html) state a bucket can only be deleted if empty